# A question about the @synthesize [property name] syntax

Tags: objective-c, properties, llvm

I just want to get a clear answer on this before I spend any more time: I'm messing around with writing preprocessor macros to simplify synthesizing Objective-C properties. One idea I've seen is something like `#define SYNTHESIZE(_X_) @synthesize _X_ = _##_X_`, which binds a property to a similarly named instance variable with an underscore prefix.

In trying to take this further, my question is, would I be able to call ever call @synthesize with a property name, but get this property name indirectly? For instance, if I do some class introspection to find the names of all the properties through a class, would it be possible to pass one of these into @synthesize, or does it have to be the actual name itself? If it's of any use, I'm compiling with LLVM 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot synthesize at runtime. That's what you're asking for - runtime code that introspects the properties and generates getters/setters. However @synthesize is a compile-time feature, and must be present in the code at compile time in order to work.

Comment: Would there be a way to add getters and setters at runtime with class_addMethod, based on the results of property introspection? From what I understand, you have to predefine an IMP to reference, so this may not be possible.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but would require you to write C functions that act as IMPs that are flexible enough to figure out what to do based on the SEL. They'd also be slower than the generated methods, and you might have issues with atomic properties. I wouldn't recommend trying.